# What is the way to add jar dependencies to a JRuby on rails app in heroku?

Tags: heroku, jar, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm a JRuby newbie and I'm trying to deploy in Heroku following these steps:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby

But I can't figure out the way to add jar dependencies. I'm using JFreeChart jars and one of my own, I'm referencing them in my JRuby on Rails app.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is, using default Heroku configuration, you cannot simply add your own jar. You can workaround this by build a gem that package with jar and use it in your app.

Assume you have jars in the lib folder. If you try to run console on your apps:

```
heroku run console

irb(main):001:0> Dir["lib/*.jar"]
=> []
```

You will found no jars inside the Heroku app location, despite the jar presented in your repo. It seems Heroku package your app in a way that exclude the jars.

As a workaround, I extract the jars into a gem, and add the gem as usual in Gemfile.

A proper solution might be create a ticket on Heroku and ask them to fix the buildpack.

Comment: What do you mean by "extracting the jars into a gem, and adding the gem as usual in Gemfile"? Do you mean you reference the internal Java classes in your Ruby code? I don't seem to get the idea.

Comment: You can package jar in a rubygems, and JRuby can read the JAR and thus the classes as if it existed locally. For an example, you can reference https://github.com/siuying/charlock_holmes-jruby

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but, place the jars in the lib directory and

```
    require 'java'
    require 'lib/myjar.jar'
```